# -bash: /home/me/.profile: line 28: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: linux, bash, shell, path

I've spent the last week of my life trying to set up a development environment so I can learn  machine learning. I have less hair now, not that I had too much before. Never mind.

I am using WSL 2 Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10.0.19054

After installing Cuda Toolkit and doing export path I now have this message when I log in

```
-bash: /home/me/.profile: line 28: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /home/me/.profile: line 28: `export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.8/bin:/home/me/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Python27/:/mnt/c/Python27/Scripts:
```

The path is much longer but I didn't put anything in it so I presume there are no errors there. I cut it so it wouldn't show the user name (is that correct to do?)

And I'm stuck.
There's no `(' anywhere.

Notes:

- I am trying to export the path for Cuda toolkit, which for the 18.8 version looks different from other versions. For instance the the "cuda" folder I've seen in other examples is now "cuda-11.8"
- The PATH has a lot of paths in "mnt/c" ... why?! I haven't installed anything there? Are they installed by Windows?

I am not a complete idiot. I know a bit of DOS and I understand Environment and Paths and syntax and stuff like. But my goal is not to learn Linux, I'm not a coder. I'm a 3d generalist trying to run some apps. Please fell free to educate me in how I should make posts here and I really hope someone will help me.

This is my first question here and also a total absolute newb in Linux. So please be kind :)

Comment: There really has to be a `(` for the unexpected error to make sense. Do you see more context if you run the file with `bash -x /home/me/.profile`?

Comment: Shortening the `PATH` is slightly dubious in this case if it really tells you that that's where the error is. `/mnt/c` (with a leading slash, which is significant) is indeed how Windows paths are exposed, so presumably yes, this is a feature of WSL.

Comment: Please upload `/home/me/.profile` to e.g. pastebin.com or edit your question and paste it here.

Comment: `"mnt/c" ... why?!` because you run WSL. `Are they installed by Windows?` *installed* is not the right word, but yes, it's because of Windows - you can stop that happening by editing(creating) `/etc/wsl.conf` and adding two lines, `[interop]` and below that `appendWindowsPath = false`

Comment: Yeah it's probably because you've used an unquoted `$PATH` (something like `PATH=$PATH:/some/other/path`) and the WSL `appendWindowsPath` feature has caused `PATH` to contain something like `Program Files (x86)`. See for example [bad variable name error on WSL](https://askubuntu.com/a/1355022/178692).

Comment: Often, when I see an error reported on line *n*, the error itself is actually on line *n-1*. Posting a link to the entire file, redacted of personal information, would be very helpful.

Comment: Welcome. It’s best to remove fluff like pulling hair, machine learning, your technology skill level. Focus on the problem itself, with little distractions.

Comment: As for the problem, reporting line 28 doesn’t require the issue to be on line 28. Please post line 20-28 and change your username to Charlie (or something else). Leave and symbols like $ as is.

Comment: Thank you all for answering.

Comment: @steeldriver i used this: " export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-11.8
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-11.8/extras/Debugger/lib64
export PATH=$PATH:$CUDA_HOME/bin "

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov https://pastebin.com/5qcrT8gt

Comment: @steeldriver i see the "Program files (x86)" issue ... i think .... https://pastebin.com/5qcrT8gt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice your export:

```
PATH=… c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA …
```

Other uses of PATH are quoted:

```
PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Since your export isn’t quoted, it interprets the (x86) as a sub shell.

To resolve, quote your PATH line with “ at the start and end like the others.

Comment: yes! that worked. now when i open the terminal there's no message anymore.  Thank you!